# Flask-OIDC Keycloak HTTPS Redirect on Localhost

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, flask-oidc

This is the development setup I have. All host references are localhost.

I am using Flask-OIDC 2.0.3 along with Keycloak 22.0.3 (running on Docker as a service). The Flask app runs on port 8080, Keycloak on 9080 and I have a React UI running on port 9001.

All these services are running on **http** and not **https**

My Keycloak docker-compose file is as follows

```
version: '3.8'
name: keycloak
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3
    command: ['start-dev --import-realm']
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    environment:
      - KC_DB=dev-file
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - KC_FEATURES=scripts
      - KC_HTTP_PORT=9080
      - KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HTTPS_REQUIRED=false
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9080:9080
      - 127.0.0.1:9443:9443
```

My *client_secrets.json* is as follows

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "<client>",
    "client_secret": "<secret>",
    "auth_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:9080/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "token_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:9080/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "issuer": "http://127.0.0.1:9080/realms/jhipster",
    "userinfo_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:9080/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "token_introspection_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:9080/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
  }
}
```

I configure my Flask app as follows

```
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS = "src/main/python/config/client_secrets.json"
OIDC_REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/oidc_callback"
```

My Keycloak client configuration is as follows

[image: Keycloak client Configuration]

When I click on the sign-in URL of my UI, it takes me to the Keycloak sign-in page of the new realm I created. But I see that the `redirect_uri` has been changed to **https**.

[image: Keycloak sign-in]

If I proceed with the login, I get an error **Secure Connection Failed**

I have tried the following

- Removed **https** from the redirect_uri list in Keycloak for the client

  - Then I get an error on the Keycloak sign-in page saying "Invalid redirect_uri"
- Removed **https** from the URL in the browser address bar manually and signed-in

  - Then I get an error "invalid_grant: Incorrect redirect_uri"

**Actual question**:

Part 1: Since this entire setup is running entirely on my local machine, I an not sure where the **https** redirect is being picked up and how to prevent it? This looks like a Keycloak issue (just a guess) of redirection preference to **https** but it seems strange since the traffic originates from **http**.

Part 2: Do I need to explicitly implement */oidc_callback*. I assume Flask-OIDC will take care of handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Sudeep Hasra's answer is right.

A workaround would be to use flask's ssl_context option. This way all your app would run over ssl. Two of the most simple options are:

1. Use `ssl_context="adhoc"`
2. Use `ssl_context=("/path/to/cert.pem", "/path/tokey.pem")`

Example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True, ssl_context=("/path/to/cert.pem", "/path/tokey.pem"))
```

If you go by the second option, you must create the certificate pair. In linux you could do as follows:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365`

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Flask-OIDC. The library has a commit that forces redirect URLs to be over HTTPS.

If I change the **_scheme** to **http** in line 55, the entire flow works as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This article is mentioned in the github issue [Conversion of HTTP URLs to HTTPS in request_uris](https://github.com/fedora-infra/flask-oidc/issues/35).  A config setting `OIDC_OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI` was added as a part of the fix for the issue.

You can see the relevant code in [/flask_oidc/views.py](https://github.com/fedora-infra/flask-oidc/blob/2.1.1/flask_oidc/views.py#L30).

My reading of the code is: if you have `OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE` it will get converted to https. You can override by setting `OIDC_OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI`.

This worked for me:

```
APP.config.update({
    ...
    'OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE': '/authorization-code/callback',
    'OIDC_OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI': 'http://localhost:5000/authorization-code/callback'
})
```